# How to migrate containers from a local docker-compose to another host

Tags: wordpress, migration, docker-compose, mariadb

Good day!

I'm trying to migrate my local wordpress/mariadb containers made from docker-compose to another host probably to a production server.

Here's what I did:
    I created a docker-compose for the wordpress and mariadb containers locally. I then started to populate wordpress content to them.

Use Case:
    I want to export and import the containers made through docker-compose along with its data to another server.

Please guide me on my problem.

Many thanks.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you wouldn't be storing data in the containers. You want to be able to destroy and recreate them at will. So if that's what you have I'd probably recommend figuring out how to copy the data out of the containers, then deploy them remotely from images. When you redeploy them you want to mount the data directories to an external drive which will never be destroyed and repopulate the data there.

If you really want to deploy the containers with the data then I'd say you want to look at [Docker Commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) which you can use to create images from your existing containers which you can then deploy.

Answer (score 1):

This is solved! :-)
I define volumes in mariadb and wordpress services in my Compose file which created the data directories that I need. I will then tar the docker compose directory and will recreate the docker-compose in my remote server. thanks for the awesome answer. heads up for you @lecstor.